# Place image in responsive footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

I would like to put below image in a responsive footer.

[image]

I would like to display the image in footer when width is 400px like below. I would like to keep the height as like previous. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Please add a code, which will show us what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background to be

background: #eee url(image_path) center center;
and set max-wdith=100%, while setting the height to be a fixed px value;

see below:

```css
#catcat {
            background: #eee url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyc3V.jpg) center center;
            max-width: 100%;
            height:300px;

        }
```

```html
<div id=catcat></div>
```